# What is the opera music playing in Psycho-Pass season 2 episode 9?

Tags: music, psycho-pass

What is the background “opera” music in season 2 episode 9 of *Psycho-Pass*, the moment when

> Akane discovers her grandma’s ear

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The opera song playing in season 2 episode 9 of *Psycho-Pass* is [*Nessun Dorma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nessun_dorma) (*Let no one sleep*)**, an aria from the final act of Giacomo Puccini's opera, *Turandot*.